# How to get the right attrs of <a>

Tags: regex

I write a Regex to get the attrs in a  tag. But it got a problem when the attrs only has one letter

```
(\S+)=["']?((?:.(?!["']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[']?[>"]))+.)["']?
```

When it to analysis this:

```
href='www.google.com' target="_blank" title="S"
```

it will get:

```
[[href, www.google.com],[target, _blank],[title, "S]]
```

How can I get:

```
[[href, www.google.com],[target, _blank],[title, S]]
```

Comment: Don't  use regex to  parse HTML. It rarely ends well. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Why not use a `HTML/DOM` parser ?

Comment: If you can, use a proper HTML parser instead of regular expressions. What programming language are you using?

Comment: Your regularity is very complicated, try this:`(\S+)=["']([^"']+)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jqYuuq/1)

Comment: (\S+)=["']([^"']+) not work for href="javascript:alert('Hello');"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression might return the desired outcomes:

```
([^=]+)=["']([^'"]*)["']
```

#### [DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/5n8ge3/1/)

#### Edit:

Other options would be:

```
(\S+)="(.*?)"|(\S+)='(.*?)'
```

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/ArLHpC/1/)

```
(\S+)="([^"\r\n]+)"|(\S+)='([^'\r\n]+)'
```

#### [DEMO 3](https://regex101.com/r/aJAzr1/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it does not work for href=\"javascript:alert('Hello');\", it will get javascript:alert(

Comment: Sorry, actually I only need to handle this href="javascript:alert('Hello');"